# SQL performing data quality checks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do some quality checks to enure that I've imported data correctly in MS SQL

How do I go about checking that a column only conatains a valid date and not text or numbers? How would I also check if a column contains a certain amount of charcters? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look up data types and check constraints in the manual of your DBMS.

Comment: Have you already imported or you going to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular task can be achieved in two ways.

1) Set the column type as 'date' type before inserting the data. ( Insertion task will throw an exception if the data  is not in the correct date format )

2) If the date is already in the table as stored in VARCHAR format you can list the entries which are not in the right date format using the query

```
SELECT Col_Name FROM Tbl_Name WHERE isDate(Col_Name)<>1
```

The following query will help you to list all rows in the table when the length of characters in a column is less than a particular value

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Name Where len(Col_name)<@MaxLength
```

Comment: Do note that `ISDATE(...)` won't return desired results if the type would evaluate to a `datetime2` type (eg, fractional seconds to 6 places).  It's also dependent on the default format of the db (eg, `10/31/2013` returns true only if the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, not `yyyy-mm-dd`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the proper [data types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271(v=sql.80).aspx) for columns in your tables. All data validations must be part of [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load):

The typical real-life ETL cycle consists of the following execution steps:

- Cycle initiation
- Build reference data
- Extract (from sources)
- Validate
- Transform (clean, apply business rules, check for data integrity,
  create aggregates or disaggregates)
- Stage (load into staging tables,
  if used)
- Audit reports (for example, on compliance with business rules. Also, in case of failure, helps to diagnose/repair)
- Publish (to target tables)
- Archive
- Clean up

So all data validation and transformations must be done on Validate and Transform phases and before Load data.

Comment: but that does not help much if you are importing some kind of legacy data you still have to do some kind of ugly comparison, just saying you have to use the proper data types would be just the start...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, It is a part of ETL process (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). All data checking and transformation must be done during transform phase and before load phase of ETL